# Is it possible to fetch actions Feed, Ticker, Timeline Impressions and other values for Facebook Open Graph apps from FB insights programmatically

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-opengraph

I have been trying to fetch Published Actions, Total Impressions, Total Referrals, Feed Impressions, Ticker Impressions, Timeline Impressions and other values for Facebook Open Graph apps from Facebook insights writing code.

I could just fetch limited parameters values.

Application Users:

```
application_active_users/
application_active_users_locale/
application_active_users_city/
application_active_users_country/
application_active_users_gender/
application_active_users_age/
application_active_users_gender_age/
application_installed_users/
application_installed_users_locale/
application_installed_users_city/
application_installed_users_country/
application_installed_users_gender/
application_installed_users_age/
application_installed_users_gender_age/
application_installation_adds/
application_installation_adds_unique/
application_installation_removes/
application_installation_removes_unique/
application_permission_views_top/
application_permission_views_top_unique/
application_permission_grants_top/
application_permission_grants_top_unique/
```

Application Content:

```
application_comment_adds/
application_comment_adds_unique/
application_photos/
application_photos_unique/
application_shares/
application_shares_unique/
```

API Performance:

```
application_api_calls/
application_api_calls_top/
application_api_calls_unique/
application_api_errors/
application_api_errors_rate/
application_api_errors_top/
application_api_time_average
```

My questions are:

- Are there limitations from Facebook Insights which do not allow us to fetch these information?
- Is there any alternative way to fetch this information?