# Facebook Graph API explorer does not display installed app data?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-insights

I used to fetch installed app data using Facebook Graph API explorer https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer

For last few months i did not work on Facebook Graph API explorer. 
i have posted one question after doing some fetching app insight information as here:  [Is it possible to fetch actions Feed, Ticker, Timeline Impressions and other values for Facebook Open Graph apps from FB insights programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12642753/is-it-possible-to-fetch-actions-feed-ticker-timeline-impressions-and-other-val) on Sept,2012.

Last two days i am trying to fetch the app information using the Facebook Graph API explorer, but it does not give me any detail info.

I can only fetch app basic info, but nothing else.
(Please see attached figure 1)!

[image]

For example, i am trying to fetch "application_active_users_city" using the insights parameters, but it does not give me any information!??
(Please see attached figure 2)!

[image]

Can anyone please tell me where is the mistake i am doing?

Advance thanks to all.

Comment: I don't know if you solved this or not, but did you check the access token? It may have expired, meaning you need to use "Get Access Token" to get the correct permissions again.

Comment: Hi Scutterman, thanks for your comment. I have already fixed the issue. The problem was in read permission. I have set up that. now i can fetch all information.